# Export PostGIS data from one database to another with multiple geometry fields (ogr2ogr)

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr, ogr2ogr

I am trying to copy the data from one database to another database. Both the source and target tables have 2 geometry columns -- a polygon field and a point field. There are `NOT NULL` constraints on both of these columns.

My ogr2ogr command looks like this

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -append -update -sql "select polygon_geom, centre_geom, id, category from sourceschema.table1" PG:"dbname=db1 host=host1 port=5432 user=user password=password" PG:"dbname=db2 host=host2 port=5432 user=user password=password" -nln targetschema.table1
```

However I can't get ogr to recognise the 2 geometry fields. The error i get is:

```
ERROR 1: ERROR:  null value in column "geom" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I copy this data across my 2 databases properly? Even if I export just one geometry column, the NOT NULL constraint on the other column will still prevent me from inserting data. Or do I just lift the not null constraints for the time I'm transferring data across?

EDIT: The source and target tables are not exact copies of one another - the target table has more columns than the source.

Comment: another alternative is to use \copy piped between the 2 DB https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2013/11/21/copying-rows-between-postgresql

Comment: @JGH thank you- unfortunately my tables are not exactly the same. I've edited the post to reflect this information. I know `ogr2ogr` has a `-fieldmap` option which is why  I initially thought it would be the best choice.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can specify the columns on both sides `\copy (select a,b,c from table1) TO ...` ... `\copy table2(d,e,f) FROM ...`   The names do not have to be the same and you don't have to export/import all columns. The default value will be used for the omitted columns

Answer (score 1):

Dont know much about ogr2ogr, but another options is to use FDW. With that, you can link data from one database directly to another. Then you can access these data as if they are in target database, without man in the middle software. This is much cleaner, because it uses plain sql, without extra hassle of ogr2ogr. It is more complicated for first setup (defining server, make foreign tables, etc) but then it is a breeze. There are some references:

- [Using FDW with PostGIS](https://carto.com/blog/postgres-fdw/)
- [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)

Comment: I've had a read into FDW. It seems that it is most useful when wanting to routinely access a remote server. In my case, i just wish to migrate data from one database to the other so i can switch off the first server. Would FDW still be ok for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, it will. Just remove any defined FDW objects after source database shut down. There are also another options. For example DBeaver has pretty good import/export capabilities. It can transefer data between two database connections. We use that pretty often. Also pg_dump should work for that.